# How can I apply a uniform type conversion to all objects of a particular class in a nested structure?

Tags: python

Assume that we have differing objects of an arbitrary class Foo in the following structure

```
a, b, c, d = Foo('a'), Foo('b'), Foo('c'), Foo('d')
nested_structure = {'key1': [a, b, c], 'key2': [d]}
```

Now, I want to convert every object of type `Foo` in this structure from `Foo` to `FooTwo` **while keeping the original hierarchy of the nested structure**. For the type conversion, we can use a given function `convertToTypeFooTwo(someObjectOfFoo: Foo) -> FooTwo`.

---

So for this particular example, the final result should be something like that:

```
converted_a, converted_b, converted_c, converted_d = convertToTypeFooTwo(a), convertToTypeFooTwo(b), convertToTypeFooTwo(c), convertToTypeFooTwo(d)
converted_nested_structure = {'key1': [converted_a, converted_b, converted_c], 'key2': [converted_d]}
```

Is there a neat and short way to achieve that? If it simplifies the question, you can also assume that the nested structure will always be a dict with the structure `{'key1': ListOfFoo, 'key2': ListOfFoo, ...}`.

Comment: I was trying something like `{k: convertToTypeFooTwo(y) for k, x in zip(nested_structure.keys(), nested_structure.values()) for y in x}` but this overwrites the values and doesn't create a list. But maybe this can be fixed somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
{k: [convertToTypeFooTwo(y) for y in x] for k, x in nested_structure.items()}
```

This works for this case.